# Tell if Swift has cached URLRequest

Tags: swift, url, caching

I am not currently interested in changing the default caching policy Swift has on `URLRequest`s, but I would like to know if a particular request has been cached or not. Is there a method on the `URLRequest` object that will tell me this?

For context, if a `URLRequest` has been cached, I don't want to show a loading screen (because it will load fairly quickly). But if a `URLRequest` hasn't been cached, I do want to show a loading screen / circle so the user isn't staring at nothing for a second or so.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer linked to the right source. But the particular method I found that worked for me was the `cachedResponse` method on the `URLCache.shared` singleton class. Passing the `URLRequest` object to this method will return an optional--nil if the `URLRequest` hasn't been cached; the value if it has.